# Alternative to "If you remember"

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

"If you remember, we discussed our research a few years back over a phone meeting". Is there a more formal or polite alternative to "if you remember" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rephrase the sentence to the following:

> Do you remember the research paper we discussed over a phone meeting a few years ago?

Alernatively, you can use the word **'recall'** or the phrase **'call to mind'**.

Your syntax is just as important as the diction; that is, the framing of the sentence should be given just as much attention as the choice of individual words.